# Copy a folder into a mounted volume within a Docker Container

Tags: docker, containers, volumes

I have a Dockerfile for an image that generates a `vendor/` folder at `/home/ics199/vendor/`. I want to copy this folder into `/var/www/html`. The problem is I am also using `/var/www/html` as a volume mounted with the host. If I copy the `vendor/` folder over to `/var/www/html`, it gets hidden when the volume is mounted and can't be used. So, it needs to get copied after the mount. I want it to be copied within the container to preserve file permissions (not container->host->container) although I understand that as a side effect, it will appear in the host's mounted volume. What is the best way to do this (preferably automatically)?

Comment: You'd need to do the copy at container runtime (i.e. via `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`), I believe.

Comment: Do you want your folder structure inside the container to be `/var/www/html/vendor`? If so, you could use `-v` twice in your `docker run` command, where you first do `-v /foo/bar:/var/www/html` and then `-v /home/ics199/vendor:/var/www/html/vendor`.

Comment: I don't think that would work because `/home/ics199/vendor` isn't on the host, it's in the container. Right now, I am doing `docker exec -it <container id> bash` and then `cp -R /home/ics199/vendor/ /var/www/html` manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in the entrypoint as Oliver suggests, but instead of a copy, you may be able to use a symbolic link to a folder inside your container:

Sample entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

ln -sf /home/ics199/vendor /var/www/html/vendor
if [ $# == 0 ]; then
  set -- /bin/sh
fi
exec "$@"
```

And the Dockerfile would include:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: Would this cause problems if the base image already has an ENTRYPOINT? According to the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), only the last one gets executed.

Comment: You would need to update the existing endpoint with your ln command, or call their endpoint at the end of yours.